# How can D3 read csv from url?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I would like to read a csv file from the given url link. This didn't work. Anyone can help me?... Thank you

```
d3.csv("example.abc.csv", function(data){
    console.log(data);    
});
```

Comment: Why did it not work? Did you see any errors in the web console?

Comment: The error is "XMLHttpRequest cannot load example.abc.csv. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8888' is therefore not allowed access."

Comment: How do you call the above script? From local file system (`file://` protocol)?

Answer (score 0):

```
d3.csv("http://learnjsdata.com/data/cities.csv", function(data) {
    console.log(data[0]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Without more details, the only thing I can think of is that you are trying to load a file on a different URL / port than your script is running in the browser (e.g. the script is running on `http://localhost:3000` and your data file is being loaded from `http://localhost:8888`).

Basically, the error that you are getting is telling you that the data file can't be loaded because it exists on a different URL / port than the URL / port that the script that is trying to retrieve it.